# SOLVED: How to fetch and show image in laravel?

Tags: database, image, model, laravel-7

hope you all right. I am working on a project in laravel where i have to store user logo in MYSql database and retrieve when user demand. I successfully stored logo path in database now i want to show it on a view but unlucky i can't. Logos are stored in 'storage/app/public/'. I tried asset function and all the possible ways i find on google and stackoverflow but no luck.

**Controller function to store**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->file('logo')->store('public');
    $company = new company;
    $company->name = $request->input('name');
    $company->email = $request->input('email');
    $company->website = $request->input('website');
    $company->logo = $path;
    $company->save();
    $request->session()->flash('status', 'New Record added successfully');
    return redirect('company');
    
}
```

**View**

```
  @foreach($data as $company)
<tr>
  <th scope="row">{{ $company->name }}</th>
  <td>{{ $company->email }}</td>
  <td>
  <img src="{{ asset($company->logo) }}" alt="" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
  </td>
  <td> {{ $company->website }}</td>
  <td>
  <a href="{{ URL::to('company/'. $company->id. '/edit') }}">Edit</a>
  <a href="{{ URL::to('company/'. $company->id. '/destroy') }}">Delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Where i am wrong??? Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Error is on your `$company->logo`its not save currectly

Comment: @STA ellaborate your comment plz

Comment: You saved the file name in `logo` field on `companies` table. do you check it correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this out, let me know if it works or not.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Image upload
    if($request->hasFile('logo')){
        $image = $request->file('logo');
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $image->getFilename().'_'.date('d-m-Y_h-i-s').'.'.$extension;
        Storage::disk('public')->put($fileName,  File::get($image));
    }else{
        $fileName = null;
    }
    $company = new company;
    $company->name = $request->input('name');
    $company->email = $request->input('email');
    $company->website = $request->input('website');
    $company->logo = $fileName;
    $company->save();
    $request->session()->flash('status', 'New Record added successfully');
    return redirect('company');   
}
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($data as $company)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
            {{ $company->name }}
        </th>
        <td>
            {{ $company->email }}
        </td>
        <td>
            @if($company->logo !== null)
                <img src="{{ url('storage/'.$company->logo) }}" alt="" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
            @else
                <img src="{{ asset('path_to_url_default_logo_image') }}" alt="" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
            @endif
        </td>
        <td> 
            {{ $company->website }}
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="{{ URL::to('company/'. $company->id. '/edit') }}">Edit</a>
          <a href="{{ URL::to('company/'. $company->id. '/destroy') }}">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i am facing " Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found ".

Comment: @Nomanmarwat Use this at the top of the controller, `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
`

Comment: images are saved but not showing in blade view. I followed exactly your code

Comment: Did you ran `php artisan storage:link` ? to create symlink to your storage folder into public folder.

Comment: THANK YOU sir, all is working fine after running "php artisan storage:link" command.